# Is there a time delay before Google Adsense ads are shown when you first put the ad code on a new website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, advertising, godaddy

I have recently created a new website and have added a Google ad in the header area and also Google Analytics.

However on the website the ad space just adds some padding rather than showing the advert. Is there a time delay before an advert appears on a new website?

Previously I had a blogger site which was approved to use Google AdSense. Now I have a new website so I went to "Content > URL channels" and added my new site then "Content > Ad units" and then generated the code for a banner. I then inserted the code into the HTML. My website is hosted with GoDaddy.

Comment: For any new site, it takes a bit of time for Google to better figure out what advertising is content appropriate. You should see Google crawling the site once you add the ads within a day or two and may for a period to create the metrics and data needed for users to bid on your site. Otherwise, ads can be based upon user interest over content until the work is done.

Comment: If it is already more than 2 hrs, then double check if your ad unit code is correct and placed correctly in the header. Also, check in Settings->Site Management that your site is listed in owned sites.

Comment: On the Content > Ad units page as the status it says new, my old blogger site says Active instead though so i guess i need to wait until the site says Active also.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the website is approved with google, or else you won't see ads.

Then when you add new adsense code for the first time, then advertisement box will initially be similar to an iframe with a system message from your web browser indicating that it can't connect to some URL. Once enough people view the page, then advertisements will start rolling in. I'd expect roughly 15 minutes to two hours of delay before the ads appear depending on how busy your website is.

There is also a section in adsense (I think under settings) where you can list all domains that are allowed to have your adsense code on it. I know that if someone uses your adsense code on a domain not approved by you (a.k.a not in the list) then you won't earn any money or penalties on those ads, however I did not test enough to see if your code on unapproved domains actually generates ads or not, but nevertheless, add your domain to the approved domains list.

Answer (score 0):

The same was happened to one of the pages on my blog. But after 48 hours, the ads started showing.  Sometimes there is some glitch on Google's side, so be patient.